# What Kind of Ant is this?

Tags: ants

Trying to identify what kind of ants we have in our home in Quebec Canada. Help! I think they may be carpenter ants?
Photos: https://imgur.com/a/mX8BvWI

Comment: An idea of the scale is required

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Perhaps better posted on the Biology stack.

Comment: Imgur is a bad place to host images, they do things like block VPNs without an error message.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, based on your location you are very likely looking at a Black Carpenter Ant (*Camponotus pennsylvanicus*).

[image: Black Carpenter Ant]

They're great to have around unless they are actually nesting in the wood of your home.

If they're just coming in from the surrounding area and you want them to stay out of the house, put some vinegar in a sprayer and use it like a barrier spray around the outside edge of your home.  It messes with their pheromone signaling and will usually last around 60 days, often longer if it isn't too rainy.